# Increasing gif dimension with just whitespaces

Tags: css, animated-gif, lazy-loading

I have images of various dimensions and I wish to lazyload them. 
For example:
(without lazyload)

```
<img src='200x200.jpg' />
```

(with lazyload)

```
<img class='lazy' src='16x16loading.gif' data-original='200x200.jpg' />
<script type='text/javascript'>$('img.lazy').lazyload();</script>
```

Before they are successfully loaded, I want to display a loading gif in its place. However I also want its dimension to settle to the desired dimension prior to the image finishing loading, but NOT the gif dimension itself as the low-definition gif will be quite ugly with a zoom.

So translating the above into points:

- adding `width=200px` will stretch the rotating gif into a very ugly big one.
- not doing so will let the rotating gif occupy ONLY 16x16 of whitespace until 200x200.jpg is loaded.
- Making [a 16x16loading.gif](http://www.milktee.nu/media/loading.gif) into [actually a 200x200.gif](http://www.milktee.nu/media/loading_225x281.gif) (according to my own noob attempt), increased its file-size by 770% from 1.7kb to 14.8kb.

So is there a way to show a rotating loading gif in its original dimension but let it take up as much whitespace as I like, possibly with CSS?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're asking how to replace a loading GIF with another image and then change its dimension? Merely setting only one of width or height will do that.

Comment: Hi @reisio, thank you but I'm asking more than that ><'
I want to change the dimension already before that, specifically maybe you can visit [here](http://www.milktee.nu/media/loading.gif) and [here](http://www.milktee.nu/media/loading_225x281.gif). I want to show the latter but without the increased file size...

Comment: Thanks for the edit by the way :p

Comment: You want to increase the size of a smaller image?

Comment: Hi @reisio I've answered your question with an edit, hope this makes it clearer?

Comment: Ah. Yes, one way would be to set the initial smaller image as a CSS background image of the img element, and both can then have independent sizes.